# How does jQuery UI's tabs demo hide the dotted focus box?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-tabs

If you go to [the jQuery UI tabs demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/), when you click on one or another tab, the styles change appropriately, and in particular, you don't get the annoying dotted line focus box that wrecks the look of the tab header.

However, that functionality doesn't seem to be included in the Javascript or CSS for the tabs. The annoying focus box appears on the page I'm developing, and I'm not the only one; it also appears on a <strike>[sample vertical tabs demo](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/tabs/vertical.html)</strike> that another question linked to (edit Feb 4/13: that link is broken now. :(   ).

I've looked through both the code given on the demo page *and* that page's full source code, its CSS page and the current version of the jQuery UI tabs code and can't work out how it's doing that.

My best guess is that it's somehow done by fiddling with the size of one of the box properties of the <li> or <a> elements in the tab headers, but I'm really not seeing it.

If you know how it's done, how clearly can you explain it, please?

ETA: Prompted by a couple of questions, I just checked further and it only seems to be happening in Firefox 8.0.1 (and earlier? Hard to say.) - no other browsers seem to show the focus box on that site; does that mean it's a (since-fixed) Firefox bug? Even so, that doesn't really explain why it's happening on one page and not another.

ETA (2): I genuinely appreciate people's suggestions on how *I* would/should do it, but I should clarify that that's not what I'm asking. I've read elsewhere (mostly in other questions here) about ways to get rid of that box, and am familiar with the ones I've seen so far (again, without being less appreciative of the effort and thought). What I'm interested in is how it's being done in the jQuery UI tabs demo specifically, because - as far as I can find - it's not doing any of those things.

Edit, Feb 4, 2013:
When I go to the jQuery UI tabs demo, I now see the dotted line around the element inside the tabs. I don't know whether it was a deficiency in the browser I was using when I saw the phenomenon (seems likely, as not many other people seemed to see it), or what. In any case, I guess the question is moot.

I genuinely appreciate everyone who took the time to venture an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Which browser?  I see no dotted box in chrome.

Comment: I'm not seeing the dotted box on firefox 10 either...

Comment: Sorry, still getting used to the multiple platforms of web development. Firefox, v8.0.1. I'll fix that in my question. (I checked, and don't see the outline in Chrome - or IE - either.)

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

check out: http://www.outlinenone.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try using Javascript's [`.blur()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp) method.

Comment: Actually, I have found 2 or 3 different ways to do it (e.g. outline:0 in CSS). My question arises from the fact that the demo doesn't seem to use any of the techniques I've seen elsewhere.

Also, for what it's worth (and maybe others can let me know if I'm wrong), I've read ([here](http://www.html-faq.com/scriptingnavigation/?removefocus), for instance) that blurring an element that's meant to have focus is not good for people with accessibility concerns.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try to set focus on other element such as input box, textarea or links

Answer (score 1):

set `outline:none` in your css

Answer (score 1):

Add `outline:none` to your `a:active` CSS, though that doesn't work in earlier versions of IE. To be really sure you also need to add `.blur()` to the tab-switching event.